# How to run dmesg -w in the background

Tags: linux, dmesg, exit

So I have a command that crashes the computer, and I wanted to see the output of dmesg to figure out the reason.

I saw that there is an `-w` option that allows dmesg to follow the process, but the problem is it does not exit so I cannot run the command following `dmesg -w`.

I tried

```
>     #!/bin/bash 
>     dmesg -w & 
>     echo image.raw | /sys/device/platform/inject_frame
```

but that still doesn't run in the background. Any advice on what can I do?

The kernel version I am using is 4.9.241

edit:
Solution is provided by Harry , and is in the comment section. At the end I did `(sudo journal -fk | sudo dd=log.txt) &` to do what I desired, which is to capture the log of following actions to log.txt

To see what journalctl is different from dmesg, you can check it out here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/redhat/comments/n3b278/can_someone_briefly_explain_the_major_differences/
[What is the difference between dmesg and journalctl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367146/what-is-the-difference-between-dmesg-and-journalctl)

Comment: "but that still doesn't run in the background" – Why do you think so? What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
dmesg -w &
echo image.raw | /sys/device/platform/inject_frame

I would expect the script to continue and run the next line. but rightnow it stops at dmesg -w &.

I am new to linux, and I thought & make the process run as a background process, please do correct me if there is anything wrong with my terminology

Comment: I don't know what the purpose of `/sys/device/platform/inject_frame` is, but I really doubt `echo image.raw | /sys/device/platform/inject_frame` makes sense. The command tries to run `echo` and `/sys/device/platform/inject_frame`, but sysfs on `/sys` should be mounted with `noexec` and I don't expect any executable there. Depending on what `inject_frame` is, `echo image.raw > /sys/device/platform/inject_frame` or `cat image.raw > /sys/device/platform/inject_frame` may make sense.

Comment: Yes I understand where you are coming from. that's just how the kernel modules works, I have access to the code and it takes the path and read instead. Anyways I am more looking to see how I can capture the output of the fram injection process.

I am sure the operation works, I just need to capture informations about it

Comment: My point is `echo image.raw | /sys/device/platform/inject_frame` tries to *execute* `/sys/device/platform/inject_frame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strace -p pid` is more suitable to find out what happens while a pragram in running and it doesn't need root privileges.  You can run it in the background like this:

`nohup strace -p pid &`

and follow the trace with `tail -f nohup.out`

Comment: thank you for your advice Harry, but I don't think there is a pid for what I am doing. 

Basically there is a kernal module that allows me to send an image to a image processor by echoing the image to a folder /sys/device/platform/inject_frame. and I am trying to debug the module since the vendor did not implement the module properly, the information is outputted to the kernel message buffer.

Comment: I see, you were talking about a command in your question, not a kernel module. Depending on your syslog configuration the error message should also appear in the log. If you are using `systemd-journald` you can view it with `journalctl -k`

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I am not very accurate with my use of words. That is what I needed, was able to do what I wanted with journalctl. Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).